# How would I model this many-to-many relationship in Core Data?

Tags: database-design, core-data, model, many-to-many

I have this Core Data relationship:

`Deck <<-->> Cards <-->> Card Defaults`

But also: `Deck <-->> Card Defaults`

How would I model this so that I would be able to create a deck with many cards, each with only ONE different default? I'm not sure how Core Data would be able to associate the fact that for each deck, there would only be one default for each card. Just from the `Deck <<-->> Cards <-->> Card Defaults`, it seems Core Data would think that each card from a deck may have many defaults.

However, if I do `Cards <--> Card Default`, then I wouldn't be able to have different card defaults for different decks.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using "-->" to mean a to-one relationship and "-->>" to mean a to-many?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb when you find yourself creating a situation like:

Deck<<-->>Card
Card<-->>Default
Deck<-->>Default

... that is an indication that your model logically requires a linking entity between two of the other entities.

I think you need:

```
Deck<-->>Default<<-->Card
```

This uses the Default object to relate each Card with a specific Deck but only through the Default appropriate for that Deck.

Don't be afraid to make multi-jump relationship paths. Core Data's ability to handle very long keypaths and complex models is its great strength.

Answer (score 0):

You need a one-to-one between Card and Card Default. You also need a one-to-one between Deck and Card Default. This way, a Card Default is associated with a Deck and a Card.